# cakephp ajaxhelper using jquery with multiple buttons

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-ajaxhelper

I have the same issue that is expressed here: http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/multiple_submit_buttons_1

That page asked about the issue, but there was no solution posted that actually worked.

I have a cakephp ajax popup form with multiple buttons.  On the back end controller, when I look through the post values, the value of the button is not being sent.  This happens in all my ajax forms.  It doesn't pass the submit buttons as a form value.

My question is:  How can I get the form value of the submit button on the back end controller?  I had a solution that worked, but was quirky.  I added javascript to each of the submit buttons onclick event that set the value of a hidden input box named "form_action".

Comment: Some html and the controller code would help...

Comment: I'm working on something else right now, but I'll boil it down to the simplest possible controller code, view and javascript to reproduce the issue and post that shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the name for the button:

```
echo $this->Form->submit('Reply',array('name'=>'data[Message][reply]'))
```

Comment: I did, this never works.  I never gets pasted as a post variable.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that I use it in my apps.

Comment: Me too, in controller $this->data['Message']['reply'] == 'Reply';